# Can we apply binary search for finding key 'x' in unsorted array?

Tags: algorithms, arrays, searching

Suppose we are given A, an array of size n, comprised of an increasing sequence of numbers followed immediately by a decreasing one. What is worst case time complexity of optimal algorithm to determine if a given number x is in the array?

The explanation given on the this [site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-cs-mock-2018-question-57/) is confusing to me. How we can apply binary search on unsorted array?

They have provided following explanation => This is an application of Binary search, which has time complexity $Θ(log n)$ in worst case.

Comment: Yes, you can! Look here for an exposition: http://www.mathmeth.com/wf/files/wf2xx/wf214t.ps
or, more accessibly, here https://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/~scm/ncs/2010/03/binary-search-revisited/

**No sorting required!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find the break point (where the type of sequence changes) in theta(log n). Then we can search individually on both sides of the break point (each of which is a sorted sequence). So overall theta(log n) only.

Answer (score 2):

First use binary search to find the index, where the ordering changes from increasing to decreasing.
Now you can use binary search on both partitions of the array.

Comment: You mean to say break point increasing to decreasing.